# The discrete topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set.  Let $\tau$ be a topology on $X$ which contains every infinite subset of $X$. Show that $\tau$ is the discrete topology on $X$.
The idea that came to my mind was to
show that every singleton subset of $X$ is in$\tau$ but how to do that?

Comment: Choose any point in $x \in X$ and use the fact that the intersection of two open sets is open to force the set $\{ x \}$ into $\tau$.

Comment: What if $X$ is Dedekind-finite?

Comment: @eyeballfrog My usual assumption is that we can assume AC unless expressly told otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P$ be a point of $X$. We know $X$ is infinite, so it has a countable subset $S$ with distinct elements $x_1, x_2, \ldots$. (That statement requires proof, which I leave to you...)

$$
E = \{P\} \cup \{ x_0, x_2, x_4, \ldots\} \\
U = \{P\} \cup \{ x_1, x_3, x_5, \ldots \}
$$
Then $E$ and $U$ are both infinite, so $E, U \in \tau$. Now $\tau$ is a topology, so $E \cap U \in \tau$. What is $E \cap U$?